# How to get the values of all checked checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I don't know how to pass the selected values of the checkboxes. Any help or suggestions will be a big help for me.

As of now here is my code I am stuck in passing the values of the checkboxes

#### `index.php`

```
<table>
<?php
foreach($response as $item){
    echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="' .$item['id']. '"></td><td>' . $item['name'] . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btnadd">AddSelected</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.btnadd').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {  }, // what should I put here to pass the value of checked checkboxes
                success: function(data) {}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### `process.php`

```
<?php
$array_ids = $_POST['ids']; // this will retrieve the id's
?>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try This.

**HTML CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btnadd').click(function(){
            var checkValues = $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').map(function()
            {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'loadmore.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: { ids: checkValues },
                success:function(data){

                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="2" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="5" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxlist" value="6" />​
```

**loadmore.php CODE**

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST['ids']);

?>
```

**OUTPUT IN loadmore.php**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
)
```

That's IT.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Use this function :

```
 function checkboxValues() {         
     var allVals = [];
     $(':checkbox').each(function() {
       allVals.push($(this).val());
     });
     return allVals; // process the array as you wish in the function so it returns what you need serverside
  }
```

and your ajax call will look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { checkboxValues() }, 
    success:function(data){         }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this before your ajax call:

```
var ids=[]; 
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
    ids.push($(this).val());
});
```

But it is strongly recommended to wrap your checkboxes in some div, and represent it in your jquery selector. Because in current way you can select and send to server some other checkboxes on your page.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your checkboxes in a `<form>` tag and name your checkboxes using PHP array notation:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="3">
</form>
```

The use [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
 $(function () {
     $('.btnadd').click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'process.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: $("#form1").serialize(),
             success: function (data) {}
         });
     });
 });
```

On the server side, `$_POST["item"]` will be an array containing only the checked values.

Comment: nice, but my checkbox is from a table not in form :) anyways thank you.

Comment: You can put the table inside the form tag. Absolutely nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Your `jQuery.serialize()` link says that serialize() does not accept any arguments, so you need to move the selector out of the parentheses and write it as a parenthetical expression after `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the checkbox list label text

```
<span> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[id][]" value="0" /> 
    <label for="mycheckboxid_0">Test0</label> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox[id][]" value="1" /> 
    <label for="mycheckboxid_1">Test1</label> 
</span>


var chkbox = document.getElementsByName('mycheckbox[id][]');
    var vals = "";
    for (var i=0, n=chkbox .length;i<n;i++) {
        if (chkbox [i].checked) 
        {
            var label = "mycheckboxid_"+i;
            vals += " "+$('label[for="'+label+'"]').html();
        }
    }
alert(vals); // output test1 test2
```

hope it's work for you

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this html:

```
<td><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chkimportsikep' class='form-control' value={$TABLE_NAME} checked>" ?></td>
```

ajax/ jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//handle test button click
$("button#importSikep").click(function(){
    var checkValues = $('input[name=chkimportsikep]:checked').map(function()
    {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    alert(checkValues);
    $('#loading-indicator-runsikep').show();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"runsikepimport.php", // your php page action
        data:{ chkimportsikep: checkValues }, // 
        cache:false,
        success: function(result){
            $('#loading-indicator-runsikep').hide();
            alert(result);
            $('.modal.in').modal('hide');
            $("#description-status-sikep").load(location.href + " #description-status-sikep");  
            //location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

PHP action :

```
    // don't need array variable, but your using $_POST
if(!empty($_POST['chkimportsikep'])) {
            foreach($_POST['chkimportsikep'] as $table_name) {
             // do something 
            }
}
```